# Is there Multimap in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I need to store values in map likie this:

```
 val map = HashMap<String, Set<String>>()
```

But it is hard to interact with Set inside the map.

Is there any multimap implementations in Kotlin like  [Multimap in Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)?

Comment: Not natively: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/

Comment: Why don't you use guava in Kotlin?

Comment: No, currently it's not in the stdlib.

Comment: @ice1000 how would that work when you compile to javascript or native? jvm isn't the only kotlin target, and AFAIK there's only a jvm implementation for guava.

Comment: @JamesMoore using sets and maps in the stdlib and `map["key"].forEach(::println)`?

Comment: @ice1000 The question was about multimap implementations in Kotlin.  Answers that require a JVM are off-topic since Kotlin isn't JVM-specific.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there currently isn't. And there probably won't be one in the future.

Reference: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/the-standard-library-and-a-kotlin-manifesto/1303/6

Alternative:

```
org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap
org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap
com.google.common.collect.Multimap
```

To play with the `Set` in your example, you can:

```
map["key"].forEach(::println)
```

Or something else.

Comment: Sadly, none of these are an option for Kotlin/Javascript or Kotlin/Native.

Answer (score 19):

> But it is hard to interact with Set inside the map.

It's not that hard, e.g.:

```
val map = HashMap<String, MutableSet<String>>()
map.getOrPut("howdy") { mutableSetOf() }.add("world")
```

Comment: synchronizing this will be a pain if needed though

Comment: @urSus agree with you here. Simple replacement of `HashMap` with `ConcurrentHashMap` would not work. I'd ask a question first: do you really need blocking synchronization? What if you'll try an Actor pattern instead?

Comment: Not really, just pointing it out for people, that if they need synchronization, ConcurrentMap<MultiMap> should work, as opossed to ConcurrentMap<HashMap<String, Set> where adding to that set will not be synchronized (just the map)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Kotlin on the JVM and Spring: you can use the `collectionUtils` for `MultivalueMap`: and you can also get an unmodifiable type: which in reality just throws `UnsupportedOperationException` on the modifications.

```
val myMap = mapOf("1" to listOf(1,2,3))
CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(CollectionUtils.toMultiValueMap(myMap))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:
`val myMap = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>().apply {add("Hello", "World")}`

Comment: If you recommend a class from the Spring framework, it's worth noting!

Answer (score 0):

For basic use, something like this can be handy:

```kotlin
class MutableMultimap<K, V> {
    private val map: MutableMap<K, MutableSet<V>> = HashMap()
    operator fun get(key: K): Set<V> = map[key] ?: emptySet()
    operator fun contains(key: K): Boolean = map.containsKey(key)
    fun contains(key: K, value: V): Boolean = map[key]?.contains(value) ?: false

    fun add(key: K, value: V) : Boolean {
        return map.getOrPut(key) { mutableSetOf() }.add(value)
    }

    fun remove(key: K, value: V): Boolean {
        val values = map[key] ?: return false
        val removed = values.remove(value)
        if (values.isEmpty())
            map.remove(key)
        return removed
    }
}
```

Of course, various optimizations to this are certainly possible.